# Python geopy returns different coordinates with or without post code

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to retrieve the coordinates of an address using geopy. However, I found some thing weird to me. The return values are different with or without the post code. I picked one address randomly in Toronto. Can anyone take a look at the following code and explain the reason? Thanks in advance.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='Test')
wAddress1 = '3159 Birchmount Rd, Scarborough, ON'
wAddress2 = '3159 Birchmount Rd, Scarborough, ON M1V 1S4'
location = geolocator.geocode(wAddress1)
lat, lon = location.latitude, location.longitude
print("Address 1:",(lat,lon))
location = geolocator.geocode(wAddress2)
lat, lon = location.latitude, location.longitude
print("Address 2:",(lat,lon))
```

The output I got is

Address 1: (43.7091996, -79.2690054)

Address 2: (43.8007037, -79.3071159)

Answer (score 1):

Running your code and inspecting the raw response, shows there are different places had been found. Add a structured query increases the relevance/importance:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='Test')
wAddress1 = '3159 Birchmount Rd, Scarborough, ON'
wAddress2 = '3159 Birchmount Rd, Scarborough, ON M1V 1S4'

# street, city, county, state, country, or postalcode.
structuredQuery = {
    "postalcode" : 'M1V 1S4',
    "state" : 'Ontario',
    "country" : 'canada',
    "street" : 'Birchmount Road',
    "city" : 'Scarborough—Agincourt'
}


for adr in [wAddress1, wAddress2, structuredQuery]:
    location = geolocator.geocode(adr)
    print(location.raw)
```

Out:

```
{'boundingbox': ['43.7989537', '43.7994487', '-79.3061331', '-79.3058715'],
 'class': 'highway',
 'display_name': 'Birchmount Road, Scarborough—Agincourt, Scarborough, '
                 'Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, M1W 2S2, Canada',
 'importance': 0.41000000000000003,
 'lat': '43.7991476',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. '
            'https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-79.3059471',
 'osm_id': 937288618,
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'place_id': 281104232,
 'type': 'secondary'}
{'boundingbox': ['43.800653', '43.8010106', '-79.3073991', '-79.3070558'],
 'class': 'highway',
 'display_name': 'Birchmount Road, Scarborough—Agincourt, Scarborough, '
                 'Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, M1W 2S2, Canada',
 'importance': 0.41000000000000003,
 'lat': '43.8007037',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. '
            'https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-79.3071159',
 'osm_id': 193009856,
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'place_id': 151161876,
 'type': 'secondary'}
{'boundingbox': ['43.8001905', '43.800653', '-79.3070558', '-79.3065873'],
 'class': 'highway',
 'display_name': 'Birchmount Road, Scarborough—Agincourt, Scarborough, '
                 'Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, M1W 2S2, Canada',
 'importance': 0.82,
 'lat': '43.8005704',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. '
            'https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-79.3069721',
 'osm_id': 32996161,
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'place_id': 114146558,
 'type': 'secondary'}
```

Note: All 3 results represent 3 different OSM objects.